# Determining a firing solution on a moving target

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I'm working on a little project for myself, and I wanted to create a fire-control system of sorts for a cannon mounted on a ship. My goal with the fire control system is to find the angles of elevation and horizontal traverse required for the cannon projectile to hit a moving target ship.

In order to do this, I first created a diagram to represent the situation, shown below:[image]

There are only a couple of known values in this situation. These known values are:

- the magnitude of the initial linear separation between the target ship and the 'firing ship', **$d_0$**
- the magnitude of the initial line-of-sight angle to the target ship, **$\theta_i$**
- the **magnitude** of the initial (muzzle) velocity of the projectile launched, $v_{projectile}$
- the vector $v_{target}$, the velocity vector of the target ship's speed. In my case, the target ship's velocity is assumed to be always parallel to the 'firing ship'.

My objective is essentially to determine the *direction* of the vector $v_{projectile}$, that is, determine the values of the angles $\theta_v$, the angle above the horizontal, and $\theta_h$, the angle from the normal, both as shown in the diagram.

I can assume that the projectile experiences no drag forces and only the acceleration due to the force of gravity of the earth acts on it ($-9.81m/s^2$).

I attempted to formulate a system of equations using standard kinematics and trigonometry, but I had no luck with this approach because of the angle $\theta_v$ being entirely dependent on the value $d_{projectile}$, which was *also* dependent on the value of $\theta_h$, which then also was dependent on the value of $d_{travel}$, the distance that the target ship travels during the airtime of the projectile, $t$ (as $d_{travel} = v_{target} \times t$). And then again $t$ is also dependent on $\theta_v$, so I think you'll see how the situation just repeats endlessly on itself.

Instead of this approach, I was suggested to utilize vector arithmetic, but I am not as well versed in how to utilize it to find the extremely elusive value of **$t$** that would allow this situation to be solved. I would like insight on how to solve this situation for the angles $\theta_h$ and $\theta_v$, for I have no idea how to do this through my current knowledge of vectors and mathematics.

Comment: The time it takes for the projectile to hit the water can be calculated directly from the muzzle velocity, and the elevation angle, and the acceleration of gravity.  Just take the vertical component $v_{projectile}\sin {\theta _v}$ of the muzzle velocity, plug it into $v= \sqrt {2gh}$, solve for $h$, then plug $h$ into $h = \frac{1}{2} g \tau ^2$ and solve for $\tau$.  The projectile must rise, then fall, so the total time before it hits the ground is $2\tau$.

Answer (score 1):

After some work, I got a system of two equations with three unknowns, $v_0, \theta _v $ and $\theta _h$. This makes sense because you can have more than one potential trajectory, with different values of the above variables. So you can safely arbitrarily assume $\theta _v =\pi/4$ to simplify your problem (this selects one particular trajectory), and from the equations calculate the corresponding other two variables

PS: the derivation is a little long to type, but is not difficult at all.

start with:

$d_0 \sin \theta _i =v_0 \cos \theta _v \sin \theta_ h t$

$d_0 \cos \theta _i + v_{target}t= v_0 \cos \theta _v \cos \theta_h t$

$t=2v_0 \sin \theta _v/g$

Comment: Is the variable $v_0$ in this case the initial velocity of the projectile? Also, regarding the arbitrary decision of the value $\theta_v$ as equal to $\pi/2$, wouldn't that make the problem impossible as the projectile would not have a horizontal component of velocity? I need the projectile to hit to target at its expected position.

Comment: yes, it is the initial velocity. And it was a typo, I meant pi/4!

Comment: were you able to follow why those equations and then compute v_0 and theta_h?

Comment: I added that the initial velocity of the projectile is known- would this change the approach to solving the situation at all? I also don't quite understand the first equation- I can't see how $d_0\sin\theta_i = v_0 \cos \theta _v \sin \theta_h$. $v_0 \cos \theta_v$ would be the horizontal component of the projectile's velocity- how does multiplying that to $\sin \theta_h$ equal $d_0\sin\theta_i$? Logically thinking, wouldn't $d_0\sin\theta_i$ just equal $d_{projectile} \sin \theta_h$, not $v_0 \cos \theta _v \sin \theta_h$?

Comment: I forgot to put the t, my mistake. $v_0 \cos \theta _v$ is the   speed on the plane along $d_projectile$, the last one being unknown, and you do not want to introduce more unknown variables. So you need to project this speed in the horizontal  direction, a distance that you can write in term of the unknowns you want. If you know $v_o$ then just compute the two unknown angles

Comment: but you will need to solve it numerically